# May I ask about name identificaton here?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, questions

I heard certain name which is foreign for me. And I want to ask "what names there are in such country that sounds similar to this".

Comment: Are you asking about place names or personal names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't off-topic, but will need to be carefully worded to ensure it's not too broad/unanswerable.

Do you have a single country in mind, and a single name?

Comment: That's correct - an Estonian name: https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/16026/what-estonian-name-is-there-similar-to-titsilt